# What causes firePHP to fail to open output stream

Tags: console, firephp

I am trying to write a javascript variable to the console but could not so I setup (I think???) firePHP but received

Warning: require(FirePHPCore/fb.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\htdocs\replayandsave\public\home\templatehome.php on line 26

line 25
          < ? php  (had to add spaces to get it to display)

line 26
              require('FirePHPCore/fb.php');

Please help I have spent four days trying to get a component to work with dynamically created parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is call `console.log(variable);` in the JavaScript code that PHP is serving. No Need for FirePHP. FirePHP is used to log PHP variables to the browser JavaScript console.